# Will I be able to show latitude and longnitude on a bluetooth device?

Tags: android, google-maps, bluetooth, google-geocoding-api

I've been working on a project and have come into a spot of bother. Is there any way I can show the latitude and longitude of a Bluetooth devices on an android app with Google geocoding API and Google Maps Api integrated or is there any other way I can do it withoit having to use a WiFi connection of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No, it depends on bluetooth device. 
If the device has inbuild independend gps chip, then its it can provide you location independently,API to retrieve and SDK would depend on the kind of hardware. So its vendor specific.

However mostly google wear, doesn't have gps chips and rely on the device that they are paired with mostly phones.

More details: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/gps-on-android-wear-devices.html

Comment: Thanks for that! Do you know any microcontrollers that have either Bluetooth and GPS capabilities or Mobile Data and GPS capabilities.

Comment: You may mail your requirement to neeraj.k.singh@intel.com, referencing me, he will identify and let u know, if intel has any such chip.. i have no contact for other companies.